# Deploying Ruby on Rails App (OpenConferenceWare) to IBM Bluemix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-cloud, gemfile

I have been trying to push my 'openconferenceware' appl to bluemix. While, the application runs flawlessly on my local system, it doesnt get deployed on the Bluemix.

Below is the log output.

```
Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: uninitialized constant OpenConferenceWare
       /tmp/staged/app/config/initializers/01_open_conference_ware.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/staged/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

Below is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'ibm_db'
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem "open_conference_ware", "~> 1.0.0.pre"
group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

and my Database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Any pointers on how to migrate the app onto bluemix.

**Addl.INFO** 
Manifest file

```
applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: csw-events
  name: csw-events
  path: .
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 1920M
```

I also tried with (As suggested in this [post](https://jeffsloyer.io/2015/03/05/tips-for-migrating-ruby-on-rails-applications-to-bluemix/)):

```
applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: csw-events
  name: csw-events
  path: .
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 1920M
  command: bundle exec rake db:setup && bundle exec rails s -p $PORT
  services:
  #swap out the below for your own
  cf cs elephantsql turtle dnxluuom
  #cf cs rediscloud 25mb yourownname
  #redis cloud has different plans, check out cf marketplace for the plans
    - postgres-myapp
```

With the second version of Manifest file, I get manifest error:

```
Error reading manifest file: yaml: control characters are not allowed at line 1, column 1
```

I use **ruby 2.2.1p85**

Building from the ruby buildpack results in the below snippet of the log file (The app does not start)

```
2015-07-23T16:21:16.22+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Bundle complete! 11 Gemfile dependencies, 69 gems now installed.
2015-07-23T16:21:16.22+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
2015-07-23T16:21:16.22+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
2015-07-23T16:21:16.24+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Bundle completed (0.61s)
2015-07-23T16:21:16.26+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
2015-07-23T16:21:18.36+0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
2015-07-23T16:21:22.48+0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
2015-07-23T16:21:22.58+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Running: rake assets:precompile
2015-07-23T16:21:23.13+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.r                                               b:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
2015-07-23T16:21:25.85+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Asset precompilation completed (3.25s)
2015-07-23T16:21:25.85+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Cleaning assets
2015-07-23T16:21:25.85+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Running: rake assets:clean
2015-07-23T16:21:26.39+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.r                                               b:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT ###### WARNING:
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT ###### WARNING:
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        ruby '2.2.2'
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT ###### WARNING:
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
2015-07-23T16:21:28.98+0200 [STG/0]      OUT        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
2015-07-23T16:21:37.09+0200 [STG/130]    OUT -----> Uploading droplet (38M)
2015-07-23T16:21:47.20+0200 [DEA/130]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a
2015-07-23T16:22:04.76+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: w                                               arning: circular argument reference - now
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant RailsStarter (NameError)
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_optio                                               ns_from_config'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top                                                (required)>'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (require                                               d)>'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.72+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T16:22:07.79+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-23T16:22:07.79+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:61596
2015-07-23T16:22:07.79+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-07-23T16:22:07.79+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-23T16:22:07.79+0200 [App/0]      OUT Exiting
2015-07-23T16:22:07.87+0200 [DEA/130]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-07-23T16:22:07.91+0200 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "dropl                                               et"=>"ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a", "version"=>"d2bc534f-8115-4e37-9504-dc0bc560232f", "instance"=>"cbb191f6bdd0440daaf5d4eac49df869", "index"=>0,                                                "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1437661327}
2015-07-23T16:22:07.91+0200 [API/10]     OUT App instance exited with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "dropl                                               et"=>"ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a", "version"=>"d2bc534f-8115-4e37-9504-dc0bc560232f", "instance"=>"cbb191f6bdd0440daaf5d4eac49df869", "index"=>0,                                                "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1437661327}
2015-07-23T16:23:31.79+0200 [DEA/18]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a
2015-07-23T16:23:59.11+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: w                                               arning: circular argument reference - now
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant RailsStarter (NameError)
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_optio                                               ns_from_config'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top                                                (required)>'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (require                                               d)>'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.67+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T16:24:03.75+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-23T16:24:03.75+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:61502
2015-07-23T16:24:03.75+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-07-23T16:24:03.75+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-23T16:24:03.75+0200 [App/0]      OUT Exiting
2015-07-23T16:24:03.89+0200 [DEA/18]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-07-23T16:24:03.92+0200 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "dropl                                               et"=>"ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a", "version"=>"d2bc534f-8115-4e37-9504-dc0bc560232f", "instance"=>"f3bbb48d0e864b29a36c93170061303d", "index"=>0,                                                "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1437661443}
2015-07-23T16:24:03.93+0200 [API/4]      OUT App instance exited with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "dropl                                               et"=>"ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a", "version"=>"d2bc534f-8115-4e37-9504-dc0bc560232f", "instance"=>"f3bbb48d0e864b29a36c93170061303d", "index"=>0,                                                "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1437661443}
2015-07-23T16:24:32.45+0200 [DEA/97]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a
2015-07-23T16:24:58.93+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: w                                               arning: circular argument reference - now
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant RailsStarter (NameError)
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_optio                                               ns_from_config'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top                                                (required)>'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (require                                               d)>'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.78+0200 [App/0]      ERR    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T16:25:03.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-23T16:25:03.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:61788
2015-07-23T16:25:03.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-07-23T16:25:03.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-23T16:25:03.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT Exiting
2015-07-23T16:25:03.99+0200 [DEA/97]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-07-23T16:25:04.03+0200 [API/8]      OUT App instance exited with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "dropl                                               et"=>"ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a", "version"=>"d2bc534f-8115-4e37-9504-dc0bc560232f", "instance"=>"7d73c9cf8dfd458b98e28349d6ac3903", "index"=>0,                                                "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1437661503}
2015-07-23T16:25:04.03+0200 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "dropl                                               et"=>"ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a", "version"=>"d2bc534f-8115-4e37-9504-dc0bc560232f", "instance"=>"7d73c9cf8dfd458b98e28349d6ac3903", "index"=>0,                                                "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1437661503}
2015-07-23T16:25:47.20+0200 [DEA/7]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid ff6f8fba-6b2c-4f38-a118-8154fe77114a
2015-07-23T16:26:15.33+0200 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: w                                               arning: circular argument reference - now
```

mainfest file

```
applications:
- services:
  - postgres-myapp
  disk_quota: 1024M
  host: csw-events
  name: csw-events
  path: .
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 1920M
```

Comment: What ruby buildpack are you using?  What does your `manifest.yml` look like?  Please update your question with these answers.  Also please check out this blog post for some tips on running your Ruby app. https://jeffsloyer.io/2015/03/05/tips-for-migrating-ruby-on-rails-applications-to-bluemix/

Comment: I have added the manifest file

Comment: @vmovva @JeffSloyer using this buildpack worked for me `push csw-events -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git -s cflinuxfs2` . The app seems to be also running on the bluemix but, I get this error `403 Forbidden ~ nginx`  any ideas as to what is causing it?

Comment: You should be using the ruby build pack not the static one.

Comment: Do you have a postgres database bound to your app?  Additionally why do you have the ibm_db gem in your app?  It looks like your app is having issue with active support.  Its stemming from `config.ru` line 4.  The error I see is `uninitialized constant RailsStarter`.

Comment: @JeffSloyer , Yes, tht was a mistake. I was playing with my `config.ru` file and forgot to change it back. The app successfully gets deployed on the bluemix now. There seems to be a problem with the app on bluemix now [link](http://csw-events.mybluemix.net/). I tried again running the app locally, it works fine.  I will try to post the log file on the main question  area.

Comment: I have seen that when you don't use the correct command to start our app or rake assets has not been run. Can you post your manifest.yml?

Comment: Is there a db bound to your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84105/discussion-between-betafish-and-jeff-sloyer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Ruby buildpack instead of the static (nginx) one.  The link to the Ruby buildpack is https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git.

To use this buildpack do the following.

`cf push csw-events -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git`.

Comment: I tried using the Ruby buildpack as suggested. But unfortunately, the app doen not start. I have added the log file to the main part of the questions. Do you see anything unsual in the log file?