# 403 Forbidden ~ nginx on Bluemix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ibm-cloud

This is in continuation to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570534/deploying-ruby-on-rails-app-openconferenceware-to-ibm-bluemix?noredirect=1#comment51097657_31570534), that I posted on SO yesterday. I am not sure if should make another questions or just link it to the older post.

Neways, I have been trying to deploy ruby on rails app onto Bluemix. After much trail and error, I finally managed to push the app and start it. But, when I try to open the web app. Bluemix throws me an error

```
403 Forbidden
   nginx
```

If I understand correctly, this has something to do with permissions to access certain folder on my RoR app. How to resolve this. DO I have to change permission on my local app before pushing it to bluemix or is there something to be done on bluemix?

Here is the [link](http://csw-events.mybluemix.net/)

EDIT :

This is my error log on **ngnix** folder on bluemix

```
2015/07/23 10:16:39 [error] 37#0: *2 directory index of "/home/vcap/app/public/" is forbidden, client: 75.126.52.20, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "csw-events.mybluemix.net"
```

ngnix.conf file on bluemix

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

error_log /home/vcap/app/nginx/logs/error.log;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  log_format cloudfoundry '$http_x_forwarded_for - $http_referer - [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
  access_log /home/vcap/app/nginx/logs/access.log cloudfoundry;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include mime.types;
  sendfile on;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/js text/xml text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/xml+rss;

  tcp_nopush on;
  keepalive_timeout 30;
  port_in_redirect off; # Ensure that redirects don't include the internal container PORT - 61596
  server_tokens off;

  server {
    listen 61596;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root /home/vcap/app/public;
      index index.html index.htm Default.htm;

    }
  }
}
```

The ngix folder does not exist on my local system. It is created when i push my app to bluemix (Or am I missing something here?)

Comment: Can you try using a simplied config for nginx first?

Comment: Also you can not us Nginx to serve your Ruby application.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the Nginx (static buildpack to serve your Ruby on Rails app.  You must use the Ruby buildpack for that.

Comment: hi there, can you check if the user that is running nginx can acces to the folder? check that user with ps aux | grep nginx, are you working with passanger module ?

Comment: You need to use the ruby bull pack

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused for two reasons (atleast in my scenario).

a) Not using the correct build pack. The one which solved my problem was using this buildpack from CF

```
cf push csw-events -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git
```

b) Sensitivity of the manifest file - Bluemix started throwing the following error:

```
FAILED 
Error reading manifest file: 
yaml: [] control characters are not allowed at line 1, column 1
```

This was resolved by downloading the manifest file again and replacing only specific part of it (like the command part).